# Change appendix name and numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

I'm using the article class where appendices appear as

A Title of appendix

B Another title

etc.

However, I'd like to have the appendices displayed as follows:

Anhang I

Anhang II

etc.

in the ToC and followed by the respective appendix title in the document. Changing the name is presumably not too hard using `\appendixname` after activating it for the article class (which I don't know how to do). However, I don't know how to obtain roman numbering.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \appendix

  \section{The first appendix}
  \blindtext

  \section{The second appendix}
  \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Appendix sections in the body should also use Roman numbering, as in the table of contents?

Comment: @Bernard Yes it should. In the body it should read the same as in the ToC but followed by the actual title of the respective appendix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that this does what you want.

```
% appnameprob.tex  SE 553677

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tocloft} % useful for controlling the ToC etc

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext

  \appendix

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Anhang \Roman{section}} % change the numbering scheme
\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}} % increase the space in the TOC for the number

  \section{The first appendix} \label{appone}
  \blindtext

  The next appendix is \ref{apptwo}.

  \section{The second appendix} \label{apptwo}
  \blindtext

  The first appendix was \ref{appone}.

\end{document}
```

It is a modified version of your MWE, for which thank you.

Following your and Donald Arseneau's comments I have added a second answer using the `appendix` package.

```
% appnameprob2.tex  SE 553677

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext

% the next commands are from the appendix package
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anhang} 
\appendixtitleon    % puts \appendixname before each appendix title
\appendixtitletocon % puts \appendixname before each TOC entry

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} % change the numbering scheme

  \section[]{The first appendix} \label{appone} % empty title in the TOC
  \blindtext

  The next appendix is \ref{apptwo}.

  \section[]{The second appendix} \label{apptwo}
  \blindtext

  The first appendix was \ref{appone}.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Depending on your end goal you might want to use bits from both answers (the `\ref` results differ between the two answers).

Comment: Peter, you aren't recommending appendix.sty? I thought it handled things like this.

Comment: @Peter Many thanks for your answer. It almost does what I want. In your example the appendix title appears in the ToC as well as in the body. However, in the ToC I only want it to say 'Anhang I', i.e. no appendix title.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau I have added a second answer using the `appendix` package. I had forgotten how comprehensive it was. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @JDecou I have added a second answer that deals with your ToC requirement (and uses simpler code).