# How to get a colon between Appendix A and the section title

Tags: sectioning, appendix, section-titles

My appendices were merely labeled "A", "B", "C" *etc.*. I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553677/change-appendix-name-and-numbering) very helpful in changing them to "Appendix A", "Appendix B" and so forth. I am trying to get a colon in between the appendix label and the section title, *e.g.* "Appendix A: Screening experiment".

I tried adding the colon to the `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{}`, but that inserts it in the wrong place, *i.e.* "Appendix: A". Of course this makes sense, but I have no clue how to move the colon to the right place.

I do not have enough experience on the LaTeX Stack Exchange to merely post a comment to said answer, therefore the question. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

EDIT: I am writing my thesis. I cannot give a full working example, because I currently have 245 pages. Below I give the template's main imports in the hope that this clarifies what I am working with.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{upreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[version = 4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\chemsetup{formula= mhchem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\pdfminorversion=7

\addbibresource{report.bib}

\title{Poly(lactic acid) filament filled with layered double hydroxide for fused deposition modelling; optimisation of additive fraction and material extrusion parameters}
\author{Philip de Bruin}
\studentnumber{18017763}
\subject{CVD 800}
\date{\today}

% Nomenclature unit command - see the documentation for nomencl
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}\si{#1}}}

% Create a custom user command or run the following 
% makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
% execute this command after compiling your file once, then compile a second time to generate a nomenclature table

% If you comment out one of these lines, the document can be compiled
% without the section, but retaining page numbers and references
% this is useful to send your supervisor a partial PDF.
\includeonly{
  contents/frontmatter,
  contents/introduction,
  contents/theory,
  contents/experimental,
  contents/results_discussion,
  contents/conclusions_recommendations
}

\begin{document}

% Note: To edit the abstract, edit the file abstract.tex
\include{contents/frontmatter}
\include{contents/introduction}
\include{contents/theory}
\include{contents/experimental}
\include{contents/results_discussion}
\include{contents/conclusions_recommendations}

\printbibliography

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix} 
\appendixtitleon    % puts \appendixname before each appendix title
\appendixtitletocon % puts \appendixname before each TOC entry

\newpage
\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection.\arabic{page}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{page}{1}
% Renew figure and page counter per Appendix using the commands above
\section{Screening experiment} \label{afd_bl_se}
\end{appendices}
```

Comment: Welcome! Really, your question should be self-contained. For example, I don't know which of the solutions in that answer you're referring to or how you've adapted it. For the second, you might try something like `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}:}`. However, this won't work if you want to use `\ref` and `\label` to refer to your appendices, because you'll get the colon in references, too. However, if you don't need that, it might be a quick fix.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: I updated the question to give more information. Unfortunately I have to use ref and label, so the proposed solution is not ideal.

Comment: Nobody but you can give a real [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). And reducing you document to a MWE is in general independent from the size of your document. For example, because your problem is with the appendix, you should be able to reduce the part of you document before the appendix very fast.

Comment: Nobody can try this because `upreport.sty` is not in the standard packages, nor we have your files, so `\include` can do nothing. Please, make a self-standing example or your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, if you use KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% To have \appendixname defined.

\AddToHook{scrartcl/appendix}{% Needs at least LaTeX 2020/10/10
  \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection:\enskip}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: with scrartcl]

Similar solutions would also work with `scrbook` and `scrreprt`. Redefinition of `\sectionformat` (or `\chapterformat` for `scrbook` or `scrreprt`) does not influence references with `\ref` or entries to the Table of Contents or the page header. But there are user interfaces to change them too.

Comment: Will the new documentclass clash with the template, or should it work the same as the article class?

Comment: @PhilipdeBruin Note, that I wrote the answer, before you've shown the "template". `titlesec` should not be used with `scrartcl`. But it seems, you are only loading the package, but without really using it. However, I cannot test without a minimal working example.